# Sql query to add comparison columns dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

My table looks like

```
   Fields       Jack    Mike    Bruce ... Tony
   Salary       150     300      125  ...  150
   CTC          100     100      250  ...  500
```

Here Jack is the base user and I need to compare the salary and CTC of Mike , Bruce ,Tony upto n columnof users in the table and add comparison rating columns such as the output looks like,

```
   Fields       Jack    Mike  Mike_rating   Bruce  Bruce_rating   ... Tony
   Salary       150     300     high          125    low          ...  150
   CTC          100     100     equal         250     high          ...  500
```

**Output Explanation**
The user list grows dynamically and corresponding rating column needed to be added.
Jack Salary is 150 and Mike is 300 . So Mike_Rating column should have  value as **high** else **low** else if two values are equal then **equal**

Any Help would be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Are Fields       Jack    Mike    Bruce ... Tony the column names, or are Fields, Salara and CTC the columns?

Comment: You should fix your data structure and store one row per name along with the associated fields describing compensation (and perhaps other things as well).

Comment: Fields Jack  Mike Bruce  Tony are the column names  and Salary ,ctc are the rows

Answer (score -1):

Create a trigger on table user. Trigger is used exactly for things like this. So, for example, if u create a trigger on table Users to be activated every time after insert, then u can get the inserted data, and using it you can make changes to your table. You would also probably want to create triggers for delete and update operations on User table. You can find details on how to create a trigger [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Aleksa !. But the above mentioned table is  temporary table used inside a Stored Procedure to get intermediate values. If I am right  ,triggers can be created only for sql tables bounded by a schema.Correct me If I am wrong